# Uneven, unsmooth and incomplete animation of text-in-span width

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

I'm adding some text inside a span to another element. Then I animate its width to 0 with a linear easing. But it's not the outcome I expected. It's kinda lagging and halfway through just closes off. [here's a video of what happens](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22496113/out2.avi)
and here's the code I use

```
$('#' + id).animate({width: '10px'}, 1500, "linear", function() { $('#' + id).remove(); });
```

How can I fix this???

EDIT: I achieved what I wanted with the following code. and since the interval is high I don't suppose that it would pose any performance issues, would it?

```
setTimeout(function() { decrementWidth(id); }, 400);

function decrementWidth(id)
{
    var width = $('#' + id).width();
    var dec = 20;
    if(width > dec)
    {
        width -= dec;
        $('#' + id).width(width);
        setTimeout(function() { decrementWidth(id); }, 100);
    }
    else
    {
         $('#' + id).remove();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohhhhh boy! It was because I had a transition set on the span element; So it was fixed by setting the following inline style:

```
transition: none;
```